# Carthage dependency build with custom flags

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I'm debugging a memory corruption issue in an iOS application using `Carthage` for dependency management.

The problem is most likely related to a 3rd party dependency. I've rebuilt the dependency with `-configuration Debug` but that didn't give me any more data.

What I'd really like to do is compile it with `-fsanitize-address` which will hopefully pinpoint the exact moment things start going wrong. Unfortunately I don't see how to do this with `Carthage`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the dependency's source code and project in `Carthage/Checkouts`. Just open it up in Xcode and tweak away to change anything you like. Then do `carthage build` to update the frameworks in your project.

Just be aware that the next time you do a `Carthage update` it will blow away any of the mods you've made. `Carthage/checkouts` only contains exported versions of the dependencies. Not git repos.